# stop expanding subfolder directory

Tags: asp.net, master-pages

Im having a menu on my .master page, but my pages are in a subfolder. so everytime the page is loaded it adds the subfolder directory to the path. like this:

first load: Pages/Login/create.aspx
second load: Pages/Login/Pages/Login/create.aspx
third load: Pages/Login/Pages/Login/Pages/Login/create.aspx
And so on.

How do I solve this.

Comment: Are you using `<asp:Menu />`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess your url in the menu is something like "Pages/Login/create.aspx", but it should be "/Pages/Login/create.aspx"

Answer (score 0):

Use app relative paths, e.g. `~/Pages/Login/create.aspx`.